# SQLiteStudio export also a database file that can be read in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I get the sqlite database in android by using pull a file from the device in the file explorer and then using the SQLiteStudio to view the contents of the database.

I added some data on it and then my problem is that how do I export it that it can also be read on the android device? Because when I export the database file the format will be on HTML, PLAIN, SQL and XML.

Comment: How did you export from SQLiteStudio to the db file?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the data will change the database file you've pulled.

Just push the database file back onto the device.

Comment: Hello thank you for answering. My problem is that it seems when I push the databse file back onto the device, android does not recognize it. That's my problem..

Answer (score 0):

stop the application and then push the db back to the same data/data/databases folder.

Comment: if it doesn't work, let me know.. there are more commands that can make it work

Comment: Thank you for answering! I will try this and let you know the results. :)

Comment: @Aun
i'm exporting a database from SQLITE STUDIO to a .db file. This file get copied in the data/data/databases folder. But when I pull that same file and open it in Studio, all the table schema and data are gone. Can you suggest what am I doing wrong?